# iOS 9 App freeze with console log "BKSendHIDEvent"

Tags: ios, freeze

After app launched for a long time,
there are some logs in console while touching the screen:

`BKSendHIDEvent: IOHIDEventSystemConnectionDispatchEvent error:0xE00002E8 -- Unknown event dropped`

and all buttons have no response, whole app freeze.
Currently, this problem only happened on iPhone 5s.

Similar issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55646/alot-of-annotation-on-mkmapview

Does anyone have the same issue?

**Update**: I've found that there are more than 500 threads when app being killed by iOS, because I use a third party class Reachability too many times. To fix that, I declare a static variable, the freeze seems not happen again.

```
static Reachability *staticReachability;
+(NetworkStatus)detectNetwork{
    if (staticReachability == nil) {
        staticReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        [staticReachability startNotifier];
    }
    NetworkStatus status = [staticReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

In My case it happends after switch off wifi in iPad (OS 9.1). Application is unresponsive. In console I can see the same errors.

After switch wifi on, application is again responsive and I can continue.

Answer (score 0):

I have got fix for that...
In My case using swift, with Xcode 7.2.
I have used custom label, and func layoutSubviews() call infinite time and console is showing `BKSendHIDEvent: IOHIDEventSystemConnectionDispatchEvent`

below is fix for same:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

 var isSubLayoutSet: Bool = false

    override internal init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    required internal init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if isSubLayoutSet == false
        {
            //--- do your stuff related to set font or any operation...
            ///---
            isSubLayoutSet = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: so, that is "stackoverflow"

Answer (score 0):

fyi, i'm seeing the same console output "unknown event dropped" after updating to iOS 9.3.  I'm not sure if it's the OS, or a specific app running a background process, but I see it in many different apps including the home screen as well as immediately on restarting, so I think it's a bug in the latest 9.3 update.