# IOS 9 App Freeze(Button no response) with “BKSendHIDEvent” error in Ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have read some articles like app freeze with BKSendHIDEvent error:
[iOS 9 App freeze with console log "BKSendHIDEvent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063166/ios-9-app-freeze-with-console-log-bksendhidevent), but my problem is slightly different from this one. Since I use ionic to build the ios app, I don't know how to trouble shoot the detailed error in xCode.

My problem is that when the app first runs within the xcode, everything works fine, but if I stop the debug and reopen the app from the simulator, no button responses at all. The whole app stucks at this stage.

I checked the simulator system log, it shows this:

[image: System Log Error]

BTW, when I kill the app(flick up the app) while it is still debugging, the xcode says this, I don't know if this was the issue:
[image]

I have also tried to get further information from the web inspector, but this does not response either. I could not reload the page by

```
window.location.reload();
```

There are no window object at all...:

[image: Web inspector not response]

So I'm totally lost here. I don't know how to further trouble shoot this error. Can anyone please point me to a correct direction? I have no idea why the web inspector shows nothing here and how to get the detailed error info in xCode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After several search, here is the fix:
[App Freeze](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5324)

But I still do not know how to trouble shoot, in the issues above, they mentioned race condition, how to debug this?