# iOS App UI freeze when coming from background

Tags: objective-c, ios9.3.2

I'm facing a strange issue and I have no clue why this is happening.My app works fine when it is active, but the app UI is freezing when it comes from background (by pressing the home button and by locking the device).

**NOTE**:This behaviour is only observed on devices but not in simulator.

And the console is throwing the messages:

```
Jul  5 13:28:55 Tejas-iPhone backboardd[7234] <Warning>: BKSendHIDEvent: IOHIDEventSystemConnectionDispatchEvent error:0xE00002E8 -- Unknown event dropped
```

along with too many logs of :

```
Jul  5 14:41:40 Tejas-iPhone boostApp[7913] <Error>: CoreLocation: Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages
Jul  5 14:41:42 Tejas-iPhone boostApp[7913] <Error>: CoreLocation: Discarding message for event 12 because of too many unprocessed messages
Jul  5 14:44:56 Tejas-iPhone boostApp[7913] <Error>: CoreLocation: Discarding message for event 1 because of too many unprocessed messages
Jul  5 14:44:56 Tejas-iPhone boostApp[7913] <Error>: CoreLocation: Discarding message for event 27 because of too many unprocessed messages
```

I found out that CoreLocation will log the above message if the locationManager is not running on main thread.

Here is how I initialise the `CLLocationManager`:

```
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        [self runLocationManagerOnMainThread];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)runLocationManagerOnMainThread{

    if (![NSThread mainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runLocationManagerOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    self.locationManager = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.buildings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static LocationMonitor *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Please let me know if I need to mention any specific details.I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063166/ios-9-app-freeze-with-console-log-bksendhidevent) but it doesn't have any valid answers.

Comment: is that issue is repeating always in device?

Comment: yes. Everytime you make your app go to background and open it again the app freezes.

Comment: check the answers here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857323/ios5-what-does-discarding-message-for-event-0-because-of-too-many-unprocessed-m

Answer (score 0):

This is wierd . I integrated [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) to my project a while ago and I started to see that xcode terminal stopped logging logs and I have to always rely on apple configurator and NSLogger to see my logs.

After I delete the NSLogger from pods and from my project, my app started to work more faster and the UI is not freezing anymore irrespective of how many times the app is opened from background.